# Split and explode a column with several items

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame like this

```
    CHR START   END INFO
2547    X   153595089   153595228   FLNA_NM_001110556.2_ex05,FLNA_NM_001456.4_ex05
2548    X   153595754   153595922   FLNA_NM_001110556.2_ex04,FLNA_NM_001456.4_ex04
2549    X   153595998   153596116   FLNA_NM_001110556.2_ex03,FLNA_NM_001456.4_ex03
2550    X   153596199   153596468   FLNA_NM_001110556.2_ex02,FLNA_NM_001456.4_ex02
2551    X   153599230   153599623   FLNA_NM_001110556.2_ex01,FLNA_NM_001456.4_ex01

# Converted in a dict-list in case you need to work around


{'CHR': ['X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X'],
 'START': [153595089, 153595754, 153595998, 153596199, 153599230],
 'END': [153595228, 153595922, 153596116, 153596468, 153599623],
 'INFO': ['FLNA_NM_001110556.2_ex05,FLNA_NM_001456.4_ex05',
  'FLNA_NM_001110556.2_ex04,FLNA_NM_001456.4_ex04',
  'FLNA_NM_001110556.2_ex03,FLNA_NM_001456.4_ex03',
  'FLNA_NM_001110556.2_ex02,FLNA_NM_001456.4_ex02',
  'FLNA_NM_001110556.2_ex01,FLNA_NM_001456.4_ex01']}
```

I want to convert the values of the last column in a list to explode that column

I am trying this

```
WRGL4_hg19.assign(tmp=WRGL4_hg19["INFO"].str.split()).explode("INFO").reset_index(drop=True)
```

I got the new column with a in each row but only one elemnet and then I believe the explode does not work for that reason

```
    CHR START   END INFO    tmp
0   X   153595089   153595228   FLNA_NM_001110556.2_ex05,FLNA_NM_001456.4_ex05  [SKI_NM_003036.4_ex01]
1   X   153595754   153595922   FLNA_NM_001110556.2_ex04,FLNA_NM_001456.4_ex04  [SKI_NM_003036.4_ex02]
2   X   153595998   153596116   FLNA_NM_001110556.2_ex03,FLNA_NM_001456.4_ex03  [SKI_NM_003036.4_ex03]
3   X   153596199   153596468   FLNA_NM_001110556.2_ex02,FLNA_NM_001456.4_ex02  [SKI_NM_003036.4_ex04]
4   X   153599230   153599623   FLNA_NM_001110556.2_ex01,FLNA_NM_001456.4_ex01  [SKI_NM_003036.4_ex05]
```

```
What I need something like this

    CHR START   END INFO    tmp
0   X   153595089   153595228   FLNA_NM_001110556.2_ex05
0   X   153595089   153595228   FLNA_NM_001456.4_ex05   
1   X   153595754   153595922   FLNA_NM_001110556.2_ex04,
1   X   153595754   153595922   FLNA_NM_001456.4_ex04
...
```

The INFO column may have one or two items although in the example provided all rows have two.

Comment: You used the `.split` and `.assign` code to create a new column named `tmp` that has the data that you want to explode with... then try to explode with the source `INFO` column, which has not changed. Of course it don't have the desired result. `tmp` is what you need to explode on. And yes, you will need to tell it what to `split` on; `,` is not default. Voting to close as a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the [`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) pattern from `" "` (*the default*) to `","` and you're done.

> `Series.str.split`(*pat=None, *, n=- 1, expand=False, regex=None**)
> Split strings around given separator/delimiter.
>
> pat : str or compiled regex, optional
> String or regular expression to split on. **If not specified, split on whitespace.**

```
out = (WRGL4_hg19.assign(INFO=WRGL4_hg19["INFO"].str.split(","))
                 .explode("INFO").reset_index(drop=True) # no need for temporary column
```

Output :
​

```
print(out)

  CHR      START        END                      INFO
0   X  153595089  153595228  FLNA_NM_001110556.2_ex05
1   X  153595089  153595228     FLNA_NM_001456.4_ex05
2   X  153595754  153595922  FLNA_NM_001110556.2_ex04
3   X  153595754  153595922     FLNA_NM_001456.4_ex04
4   X  153595998  153596116  FLNA_NM_001110556.2_ex03
5   X  153595998  153596116     FLNA_NM_001456.4_ex03
6   X  153596199  153596468  FLNA_NM_001110556.2_ex02
7   X  153596199  153596468     FLNA_NM_001456.4_ex02
8   X  153599230  153599623  FLNA_NM_001110556.2_ex01
9   X  153599230  153599623     FLNA_NM_001456.4_ex01
```

Comment: You might also mention the part where you fixed the name of the `.assign`ed column :) But really, I think this is just two separate typos, and not a useful question.

Comment: It seems like you missed my comment where I mention that replaced the `tmp` column. And I don't think that it's a typo but if you think it's not, feel free to close the Q ;)

Comment: You mean the *code* comment that's partly hidden by a scrollbar, and describes an essential change as "this other thing wasn't necessary"?

Comment: I woudn't interpret it like that! I just included the modification description as a comment in the code. Again, I really don't mind if you close the Q so I can hide my answer afterwards ;)